# Cross-compilation of gdb for MIPS32

Tags: cross-compiling

I am new to build development on a host platform and have a very basic question on cross-compilation of `gdb` for MIPS32.  Do I need a GCC cross-compiler to cross-compile `gdb`, or can I use the native GCC?

Regards,

Ramji

Answer (score 0):

Cross-compilation of anything requires a cross-compiler. A native GCC will only output code native to its own platform.